# Socket.io Scheduled Events Using node-cron Not Working as Expected

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm working on a Node.js and React application where I'm using Socket.io for real-time communication between the server and clients. I'm trying to implement a feature where I can schedule specific Socket.io events to be emitted from the server to the clients at predefined intervals using the node-cron library. However, it seems like my scheduled events are not working as expected, and I'm facing some challenges.

Here's an overview of my setup and the issue I'm encountering:

## Backend Code (Node.js):

I've set up my Socket.io server instances for different game modes (_ioSpareParty, _ioFastParty, _ioEasyParty) and configured them with CORS settings to allow connections from my React client.

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";

let _ioEasyParty;

const setIoEasy = (server) => {
  _ioEasyParty = new Server(server, {
    path: "/api/v1/games/easyparty",
    cors: {
      origin: "http://localhost:5173", // Update this to match your client's URL
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      allowedHeaders: [
        "Origin",
        "X-Requested-With",
        "Content-Type",
        "Accept",
        "Authorization",
      ],
      credentials: true,
      optionSuccessStatus: 200,
    },
  });

  return _ioEasyParty;
};

const getIOEasy = () => {
  return _ioEasyParty;
};

export default {
  setIoEasy,
  getIOEasy,
};
```

I'm using the cron.schedule function to schedule events to be emitted to the clients at specific intervals. For example, I'm scheduling a "reset" event every 3 minutes for the spare party, every 30 seconds for the fast party, and every 20 seconds for the easy party.

```
let ioEasyParty = gameRoutes.setIoEasy(server);

ioEasyParty.use(jwtSocketMiddleware);

ioEasyParty.on("connection", gameController.easyParity);

// cron schedule

cron.schedule("*/180 * * * * *", () => {
  // Emit the "reset" message to the client
  gameRoutes.getIOSEasy.emit("reset", "Reset message from server");
});
```

## Frontend Code (React):

In my React component, I've established a WebSocket connection to the Socket.io server and implemented a countdown timer. I'm listening for the "reset" event and handling it by resetting the timer and updating the UI.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Define the socket outside useEffect
    const socket = io(serverUrl, {
      path: path,
      auth: {
        crazygames_auth: token,
      },
    });

    let timer = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeLeft((prevTime) => {
        if (prevTime === 10) {
          socket.emit("sendResponses", buttonResponses);
        }
        return prevTime - 1;
      });
    }, 1000);

    // Reset the timer when the "reset" message is received
    socket.on("reset", () => {
      console.log("Received reset event:", message);

      // Clear the previous timer if it exists
      if (timer) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }

      setTimeLeft(20); 


      timer = setInterval(() => {
        setTimeLeft((prevTime) => {
          if (prevTime === 10) {
            socket.emit("sendResponses", buttonResponses);
          }
          return prevTime - 1;
        });
      }, 1000);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("Disconnected from EasyParty");
    });

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, [cookies, buttonResponses]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is a typo in your code where you are trying to emit the "reset" event to clients. Also you should use getIOEasy().emit to emit the "reset" event from the Socket.io instance returned by the getIOEasy function.

```js
gameRoutes.getIOEasy().emit("reset", "Reset message from server") //  getIOEasy, not getIOSEasy
```

Or you could simply use the ioEasyParty instance you created earlier to emit events, like this,

```js
ioEasyParty.emit("reset", "Reset message from server");
```

In your React component, when you receive the "reset" event, you're trying to access a variable called message, which is not defined anywhere in your code

```js
socket.on("reset", () => {
  console.log("Received reset event:", message); // 'message' is not defined
  // ...
});
```

You should update this code to include the message parameter in your callback function. like this,

```js
socket.on("reset", (message) => {
  console.log("Received reset event:", message);
  // ...
});
```

There is potentially another typo in your code,

```js
ioEasyParty.on("connection", gameController.easyParity); // check if this should be 'gameController.easyParty'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt and helpful response!